# How to Encode ' ï ' letter into unicode ' \u00EF ' in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, encoding, character-encoding, encode, urlencode

In my app I have to encode a string for Emoji using below code:

```
NSData *data = [StrToEncode dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Using above code when I encode `ï` then get result `\357` but I want Unicode `\u00EF`.

Entered string:-

StrToEncode = "This ïs â ball"

Current output:-

text = "This \357s \342 ball"

Required output:-

text = "This \u00EFs \u00E2 ball"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding

```
NSData *data = [StrToEncode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

> Updated:unicode str printing

```
NSString * a = @"This ïs â ball";
NSMutableString * finalStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    unichar ch = [a characterAtIndex:i];
    int numVal = (int)ch;

    if (numVal>'z') {
        [finalStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\u%@",[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04x", ch] uppercaseString]]];
    }else{
        [finalStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", ch] ];
    }


}
NSLog(@"finalStr %@",finalStr);
```

Comment: it's not work perfectly. it's return same ' ï ' , not return unicode. basically i want to convert latin character into unicode.

Comment: thanks, it work fine. But my actual requirement is that if my string is 'This ïs â ball' in that case currently i get 'This \357s \342 ball' using my above encoding logic but i want to get 'This \u00EFs \u00E2 ball' . please help me if you have any solution

Comment: Plz check it now. Hope it helps man. You can change this part if (numVal>'z') as your requirement

Comment: Nice, it's work perfect. But it will return '\U' instead of '\u'. please correct it if you have any solution.

Comment: Corrected . Plz check.

Comment: Thanks a lot. if you have any other solution without for loop then please help me